# How to make a 100 X 100 image in to 1000X 1000 dynamically using the cgcontext reference

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I want to make the small image (100 *100) to largeimage (1000*1000) I am using like this but this is worst practise .

Here i added it in view but i want to  draw it in context and save it ..

```
for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
      {
          for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
           {
         UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:  [UIImageimageNamed:@"images.jpeg"]];
          [imgView drawRect:CGRectMake(xCoord,yCoord,imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height)]; 
         yCoord =imgView.frame.size.height*j;

         [self.view addSubview:imgView];
          xCoord += imgView.frame.size.width;

          }
           yCoord=0;
           xCoord = 0.0;
       }
```

I want to do it using the context draw rect .   `CGContextDrawImage` how to deal this Please help.Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want it drawn on a Context use `[image drawAsPatternInRect:rect]`

Edit:

This Method will generate a new Image in the Given size. The Image is repeatedly drawn until the whole context is filled.

```
UIImage * TiledImage(UIImage *tile, CGSize size) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [tile drawAsPatternInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

In your case just write: `UIImage *bigImage = TiledImage([UIImageimageNamed:@"images.jpeg"], CGSizeMake(1000,1000));` Now you have your 1000x1000 px Image.

Comment: I am not getting how to do it can u provide me some code if possible.. thank u

Comment: I edidted my answer and added a small example. The method will generate a new Image in the given size which should look like your pictures.

Comment: not getting sir.. can u explain me in detail that is 100X100 image sir i want to repaeat that image in that context ...

Comment: I modified my answer, i hope this helps.

Comment: hello sir thank you i want another help how can we change the rotation of a image dynamically .Means it want to rotate to which angle i give..

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you would get having a 1000x1000 `UIView` and setting it's `backgroundColor` property to

```
[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:@"images.jpeg"];
```

if you want to draw in a context though:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
[patternImage drawAsPatternInRect:imageRect];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: I want to draw in a context nd save that context to photoalbum

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a background pattern to any view this way:

```
UIImage *pattern = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage-pattern.png"];
yourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:pattern];
```

I think this would be easier than the approach you currently have.

EDIT:

You can still render your view in a context and take a screenshot of it if that's what you want:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1000,1000)));
[yourView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Make sure you are using `QuartzCore lib` and have referenced the header file: `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` for this code snippet.

Comment: I dont want to do it in view i show it normally i want to do in context ad save that context